# Creating a dynamically PDF with jSPDF

Tags: angular, jspdf

I need to create a dynamic PDF.
The text content could change so their positions also.

The header cols is an object array like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Vagas Ocupadas",
        "dataKey": "occupiedVacancies"
    },
    {
        "title": "Total de pés",
        "dataKey": "totalFeet"
    },
    {
        "title": "ID",
        "dataKey": "id"
    },
    {
        "title": "Local",
        "dataKey": "movementLocation"
    }
];
```

And the content is also an object array like this:

```
[
    {
        "occupiedVacancies": "---",
        "totalFeet": "---",
        "id": 1,
        "movementLocation": "Poita"
    },
    
    {
        "occupiedVacancies": "---",
        "totalFeet": "---",
        "id": 8,
        "movementLocation": "Garagem2"
    },
    {
        "occupiedVacancies": 6,
        "totalFeet": 471,
        "id": 9,
        "movementLocation": "Garagem"
    }
];
```

It needs to be downloaded to the client, and I've tried using this:

```
    let doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'landscape', unit: 'px', floatPrecision: 2 });
    doc.setFont('Courier');
    doc.table(20, 30, this.exportData, this.cols, {printHeaders: true, autoSize: true});
    doc.save();
```

But without success... It gives me this error:

> getTextDimensions expects text-parameter to be of type String or type
> Number or an Array of Strings.

Comment: Did you get it working I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe keys of header and data should be matched. You have different keys in header and content. That may be the issue.

You can also check similar issue here: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3053